# hiding tab in pde

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I have an editor (emf editor). And I only want one of the tabs in the editor.
If I do not add the other pages, I still see one tab in the tab selection. Can I hide the tab, so the user will not see it is a multipageeditor?

Answer (score 1):

Ok... found it:

```
//the text must be empty so it will not be shown in the tab
setPageText(index, "");

//hide the tab
CTabFolder tabFolder = (CTabFolder)super.getContainer();
tabFolder.setSingle(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, a `MultiPageEditorPart` is used for more than one page, so if you want one page just simply use and `EditorPart`.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do?  You say you have 'an EMF editor'.  Is this an editor of your own devising or are you trying to override something?